# How to I return a List of DTOs from my API controller

Tags: c#, dto

I have a class :

```
public class Participant
{
    [Key]
    public int ParticipantId { get; set; }

    [Column(TypeName ="nvarchar(50)")]
    public string Email { get; set; }

    [Column(TypeName = "nvarchar(50)")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public int Score { get; set; }

    public int Timetaken { get; set; }
}
```

My endpoint:

```
 public IActionResult GetAll()
    {
        var parts = _context.Participants.ToList();

        if(!parts.Any())
            return NotFound();

        var participant = new ParticipantDto(parts);

        return Ok(participant);
    }
```

My Participant Dto:

```
 public class ParticipantDto
{
    private readonly Participant _participants;
    public ParticipantDto(Participant participants)
    {
        _participants = participants;
    }
}
```

I am trying the approach of passing the Participant object in the constructor and then assigning the Participant properties to DTO. I am aware how to do it for one Participant :

```
   public string EmailAddress = _participants.Email;
   etc
```

However, what If I want to return a List, how do I need to update my Dto to handle that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this statement,

```cs
var participant = new ParticipantDto(parts);
```

it is incorrect as you are passing the `List<Participant>` instance to the `ParticipantDto` constructor which the constructor is expected for the parameter value with the `Participant` type. You will get the compiler error for the unmatching type.

Hence, you need to iterate the list to transform each `Participant` element to the `ParticipantDto` type. You can use `.Select()` from *System.Linq* to do the iteration and transformation.

```cs
public IActionResult GetAll()
{
    var parts = _context.Participants.ToList();

    if(!parts.Any())
        return NotFound();

    List<ParticipantDto> participants = parts
        .Select(x => new ParticipantDto(participant))
        .Tolist();

    return Ok(participants);
}
```

While in `ParticipantDto`, you need to perform the value mapping between the properties.

```cs
public class ParticipantDto
{
    public ParticipantDto(Participant participant)
    {
        Email = participant.Email;
        Name = participant.Name;

        // Following assigning value from the properties of Participant to properties of ParticipantDto 
    }

    public string Email { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    // Following properties
}
```

---

**Bonus:**

You may look for [AutoMapper](https://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Getting-started.html) which is a popular library for mapping between classes. *(Wouldn't cover too much as the answer aims to focus and fix your current problem)*

Comment: Thanks a lot. Makes sense. Will definitely try AutoMapper.